# Internal Server Error "Invalid command 'RewriteCond%{REQUEST_FILENAME}"

Tags: 500-error

500  Internal Server Error.

Need help for my website.

.htaccess ---------

> [Sat May 09 01:35:16.765194 2015] [core:alert] [pid 671798] [client 203.82.197.51:50570] /home/username/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteCond%{REQUEST_FILENAME}', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

please help me

Comment: [500 Internal Server Error Image](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-twrDz4IJxnk/VU2vCh9mvzI/AAAAAAAAAas/gUPODvG8g3A/s1600/Capture.PNG)

Comment: Try reading the error message and looking at the file it relates to.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is a typo, but you are missing a space in your `RewriteCond` :

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} file.
------------^`

Also you need to enable the rewrite module for `Apache` :

`a2enmod rewrite`

Finally you need to activate the rewrite engine within your `Apache` config, before any other `Rewrite` directive :

`RewriteEngine On`

Comment: RewriteEngine On did it for me, easy to overlook in some .htaccess files